# How to display "Pages" as posts inside another page (Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress

Say I have an Front Page, and inside that page I have two sections (probably two divs: tagline and services). Then, I would like to add static content inside those two sections (in form of Pages).

1. I'm not very sure how to "classify" these pages: (e.g. tagline and services), because pages don't ahve categories or tags.
2. I know I have to use `get_pages`, but I'm not sure how to write the full function.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use get_pages();, but this might be easier: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/improved-include-page/

Usage instructions: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/improved-include-page/installation/